# Blender's IK seems to ignore the Inherit Rotation checkbox, how do I work around it?

Tags: rigging, constraints

[Here is a .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28159) I've created to illustrate a strangeness I have observed with blender's Inverse Kinematics solver.

Example 1 has an IK and the pre-yaw bone has no IK rotation restrictions.

[image: no locks]

Example 2 has an IK, and the pre-yaw bone has locked X and Z rotations.  Unfortunately, it locks the rotation to pre-yaw's parent bone, even though *Inherit Rotation* is not checked.

[image: IK locks]

Example 3 is posed without IK at all and illustrates the effect I am trying to accomplish.  The pre-yaw bone is correctly vertical, modeling the mechanics of the monitor arm.

[image: no IK]

I think the IK solver could be enhanced to obey the *Inherit Rotation* checkbox.  It could also be enhanced to obey the Copy Rotation constraint (which exists but is muted since it shouldn't be necessary).

Have I discovered a shortcoming in blender's IK?  Is it worthy of a bug report?

How do I work around this weirdness?

Comment: If this hasn't been solved you might try submitting it as a bug, I was able to reproduce this.